# Mixing flip-flop/toggles and binary state buttons

Tags: buttons, toggle, features

I'm facing a rather curious predicament. I'm working on a page with two columns. The one column has a list of actions that are essentially just things that run when clicked (so they've been grouped together as they're just one click wonders). **That column I'm not worried about.**

The other column contains a list of features that can be toggled/set. My question is this: Some of the toggle features have a **value attached to them** but one isn't necessarily better than the other, so they're not just on or off, but rather, for example "cat" or "dog" (yes it is still binary - but it shouldn't have the negative affect as one being better than the other but instead option one or two). For this reason I have made those buttons/options two state (like the first two rows). So the user can select either **option 1** or **option 2** by clicking on either button in that row (turning the button to active/indented).

The second buttons (in the last two rows) are toggles as they turn a feature on or off. When *on* the toggle/flip-flop is **coloured** and furthermore the button has no value other than turning a feature on or off.

[image]

Now is it wise to mix these two types of buttons so closely to each other or does it come across as a bit convoluted and messy when doing so? Additionally, would it perhaps be better to use the first approach for all - so make all of the options a two-button kind of thing and just put on/off in the labels? I feel it isn't wise to make the top two buttons flip-flops as one option inherently seems "better" than the other:

[image]

Clearly selecting cat in the picture above has a more positive connotation than dog. **However**, I did think about using something more neutral like:
[image]

What are your suggestions? Should I keep the buttons all the same/uniform? Use a combination? Change the flip-flop/toggle button to be more neutral?
**And Finally** is there any better alternative I may have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this solution gives equal prominence to each option and is seen on many iOS interfaces:

[image: Toggle Button]

Comment: I've opted to go with this approach - I think when looking at the minimalist example you provided it really is clear which option is selected and there is no favoritism attached to either option. Thanks!